# List<t> deserialization c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm relatively new to C#, and I ha to code a pretty big application for work. I want to fill a list of item "Server" from an xml file, with Deserialization. I know how to do this by "hard-coding", but I think Deserialization will be easier and cleaner.

So : here's my server class :

```
public class Server
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "URL")]
    public int URL { get; set; }
}
```

My XML file (the data are just for testing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ServersList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Servers>  
    <Server>
      <Name>Tata</Name>
      <URL>goulf</URL>
    </Server>
    <Server>
      <Name>test2</Name>
      <URL>http://test</URL>
    </Server>
  </Servers>
</ServersList>
```

and the code I use for deserialization (I used examples found on stackoverflow and other websites, but it doesn't work)

```
public List<T> ReadServersList<T>()
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>), new XmlRootAttribute("ServersList"));
        TextReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlPath);
        List<T> b = (List<T>)xmlSer.Deserialize(stringReader);
        stringReader.Close();
        return b;
    }
```

I call this function in the window constructor, and I have an exception thrown :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'TestWPF.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.

So, I worked at this yesterday all day long, I'm really bored of Serialzation and I think I won't find a way to solve my problem. Could you please help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: The exception you posted has nothing to do with the code you posted, so not sure how we are to help you. Any chance you could test your deserialization in a separate project to see if it works?

Comment: You would have to read the innerexception to find out whats wrong. A tip: Create a loaded event for testing and put the code in there, it is a little bit easier to debug the exception.

Comment: Hmm, the exception HAS something to do with my code, because when I comment this line :
    serversList = ReadServersList<Server>();
the exception doesn't happens

Comment: @T2o That's right, but since it is happening inside the constructor you get some noise in the exception details, put it in the loaded event.

Comment: Indeed, the message was a little bit different, and getting the BaseException with a try catch it was what I received : XML Exception, Data at the root level is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are calling `ReadServersList<ServersList>()`

You might need

```
class ServersList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Servers")]
    Server [] Servers;
}
```

And then the method would look like

```
public ServersList ReadServersList()
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServersList), new XmlRootAttribute("ServersList"));
    TextReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlPath);
    ServersList b = (ServersList)xmlSer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    stringReader.Close();
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand "Server [] Servers;" what does it do ?

Comment: Since <Servers> is child of <ServersList> and further, multiple  <Server> s can be children of <Servers> in the xml

Comment: I perhaps missed something, but your method doesn't work. And I always the same exception XML, so I think something is messing with my xml file, perhaps root attributes or idk.

Comment: @T2o If you want to know how xml should looks like just try to create List<Server> at runtime, add one Server instance and serialize it. I suppose that Servers root element is not expected by deserializer (as **bit** said)